# MS excel button Copy Insert & delete

Tags: excel, button, insert

I had a coding suggested by others, but i no fully match my requirements. What i need are "INSERT" those data to another worksheet rather than "PASTE" them, because when using "PASTE" previous data will be overwrite.

Below are the coding, any can help to change the "PASTE" to "INSERT"? I had try many times also error.

```
  Private Sub All_Click()

  With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    'turn off AutoFilter if it is on
     If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
     'set a CF rule for <Now
     With .Range(.Cells(2, "L"), .Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp))
     .FormatConditions.Delete
     With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression,Formula1:="=$L2<NOW()")
     .Font.Color = vbRed
    End With
    End With
    'add an AutoFilter for red font cells
    With .Range(.Cells(1, "L"), .Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=vbRed, _
                    Operator:=xlFilterFontColor
    End With
    'deal with the red font cells
    With .Range(.Cells(2, "L"), .Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp))
        If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
            With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                'select them (there are better ways to get things done)
                '.Select
                'copy them to sheet2 (do not need Select for this)
                .EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A4").Rows("1:1")
                'delete them
                .EntireRow.Delete
            End With
        End If
    End With
    'turn off AutoFilter
    If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to paste them after existing data on your Sheet2, you need to find the last row on that sheet and set your destination as that row + 1.